# How can I add an "as of date" in a benefits marketing census in Cognos Business Intelligence?

Tags: reporting, business-intelligence, cognos

I am working on a report to show the benefits and deductions for our employees and it's sending me tons of data per employee.  So, I think I need an "as of"/current deductions/benefits for the employees.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?  The report is based off of the Benefits Admin. package.  Any help would be great!  Thank you!

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to adequately address it. Try asking a more general question whose answer you can then apply to your situation. We don't know your data or your packages so mentioning them doesn't help. You can however provide basic information about the types of data you want and how you want to manipulate them.

Comment: Try putting a filter on your Time/Calendar dimension.